# How can I return the static variable in the following code?

Tags: c#, static-variables

How can I return the static variable in the following code??

```
class Program
{ 
    public static int output;
    public void MethodName(string str)
    {
      ....#some code#
     }
}
```

Without using Console.WriteLine().... I would call in the Main() method, so I don't want to use Console.WriteLine();

Comment: `return output;`?

Comment: what do you mean with return? If you want a method to return a variable then you change your method to `public string MethodName(...)` and inside the method you write `return output;`

Comment: output has no Type, this isn't valid C#

Comment: To post code snippets on SO, prefix every line of the code with at least 4 spaces. The `{}` Button will do this for you if you select the code and click the button

Comment: this is how the program was given in the question.. the Main() method was pre-written so it was not shown in question. And I was asked to write thecode and return the answer by the output variable. But I could not understand how to return the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't return anything from a method that is marked as `void`

Change the method from `void` to whatever type `output` is, then `return output`

```
class Program { 
  public static string Output; 

  public string MethodName(string str) {

    return Output;

  } 
}
```

Changes made:

- Added type of `string` to output member
- Renamed member to Output; this is how we name public things in C#
- Changed void to string to match #1
- Added `return Output` to the method

There isn't much point returning it, mind - being public static any external class that wants it can just say `Program.Output`

Answer (score 1):

You can check it online in here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bWHEcN

```
public class Program
{
    
    private static string output;

    public void Main()
    {
       string returnedByFunction = MethodName("Hello");
       Console.WriteLine("Method returned: " + returnedByFunction );
    }

    public string MethodName(string str)
    {
      return output;
    }
}
```